# Validate a form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf, validation

I am working on an AngularJS form validation. Below is the form 
[image: Input form]

I have three variables `toolId`, `timeRemaining` and `maxQtyObj` in my javascript file and I want to validate my form fields "**Tool Id**" and "**Time Remaining**" with those two variables i.e.
Field **Toold Id** should be equal to variable toolId &
Field **Time Remaining** should be less than variable timeRemaining.

And show an alert when an user enter values for **Qty** fields greater than the value stored in **maxQtyObj** which contains SX & Qty. If the user clicks on Yes, i will proceed or else cancel the process.
Please help.

Comment: may be your database column name is differnt. please check database column name, if it is `tool_id` then you have to use it in chamel case like `toolId` Not like`ToolId`

Comment: The data columns are correct and the web services are working as expected. I have tested the output which is getting in a variable . I am not sure how to implement that for validation.

Comment: It just a syntax error on `TimeRemaining: $scope.time_remaining,`, so i guess you did spelling mistake or remove that line and try to run again.

Comment: @ojuskulkarni These all are working as expected. I want to know how to proceed further with validation.

Comment: Let me simplify further.. I have two variables say toolId and timeRemaining in my javascript and I want to validate my form elements Tool Id = toolId and Time Remaining < timeRemaining. Please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using ng-blur attribute. On ng-blur of all the elements i defined a function and set boolean values to variables inside these function. If its true then it will proceed in the ng-click of the defined function.